# Enabling 'selecting tool' programmatically in PDF viewer

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, pdf

I am trying to enable Marquee zoom in PDF file programmatically in .Net/C# (Winforms)

There are many articles about how to display PDF using PDF viewer (and webform). My question is how to enable selecting tools (select tool, Marquee zoom and hand tool). Refer below picture for reference.

I am able to successfully load PDF in Winform using AxAcroPDFLib.AxAcroPDF

[image: snapshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this AxAcroPDFLib.AxAcroPDF guide](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/sdk/pdf/iac/IACReference.pdf) it is not possible. The only available functions are to display and print the file, not interacting with the containing application (e.g. the **setZoom** method at page 263).